# .net core 6 api returns 404, but swagger works

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net 6 core api,  everything works in my local environment.  I can access swagger, and initiate a call throught he swagger ui, or through postman:

GET https://localhost:7194/List/ListXYZ/Item/270 HTTP/1.1

When I publish to my web server,  I can acess the swagger UI, but I get a 404 when calling the api actions, either through the swagger ui or postman

GET https://myserver.mydomain.ca/Services/Myservice/List/ListXYZ/Item/270 HTTP/1.1

Returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 24 Oct 2022 17:30:16 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1245

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't find an error in the event log, and I can't seem to figure out if this is IIS configuration, incorrect logic in my api startup, etc.  What should I be looking for here?

My controller looks like this:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ListController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGetAttribute("{listName}/Item/{id}")]
    public async Task<Item> GetItem(string listName, string id, [FromQuery]string[]? field = null)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Swagger as the front page? try to comment `//options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");// options.RoutePrefix = String.Empty;` and try to republish.

Answer (score 0):

Open program.cs,

move app.UseSwagger(); and app.UseSwaggerUI() outside the if condition, and you shall see the swagger running in your prod server.

[image: what to be changed]